# eclipse doesn't import POI dependencies in module-child project when is declared in child's pom, but yes on paren't pom

Tags: eclipse, spring-boot, maven, apache-poi

A weird case on **Eclipse** and multi-project case, everything is fine if I declare all maven-dependencies in parent's pom, but not if I declare them in child's pom (POI stuff mainly: *The import org.apache.poi cannot be
resolved*). However everything is oki on Maven-CLI and POI libs are in maven-repository.

UPDATED with POM:

```
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.4.5</version>
    <relativePath/>
</parent>

<groupId>com.company.core</groupId>
<artifactId>parent-core</artifactId>
<version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
<name>parent-core</name>    
<packaging>pom</packaging>

<properties>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    <poi.version>5.0.0</poi.version>
    <poi-ooxml-schemas.version>4.1.2</poi-ooxml-schemas.version>
</properties> 

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <!--<scope>test</scope>--> <!-- Worked fine on 2.2.0.M3, but not anymore so I commented out -->
    </dependency>
    <dependency>.. Other dependencies, etc.
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
     </plugins>
</build>

<modules>
    <module>app-module</module>
</modules>
```

In Module app-module POM

```
<parent>
    <groupId>om.company.core</groupId>
    <artifactId>parent-core</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
</parent>

<groupId>com.company.core</groupId>
<artifactId>app-module</artifactId>
<version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>jar</packaging>

<dependencies>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
        <artifactId>poi</artifactId>
        <version>${poi.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
        <artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId>
        <version>${poi.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
        <artifactId>poi-ooxml-schemas</artifactId>
        <version>${poi-ooxml-schemas.version}</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>        
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
     </plugins>
</build>
```

So, Eclipse warm me on importing..

```
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFRow;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFSheet;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook;
```

Eclipse: 2021-03, Spring Boot 2.4.5, POI 5.0.0.
Configuration: One parent project (ONE), Two module (A, B).
ONE has spring-boot-starter-parent (packaging pom) artifact and being used by A and B. Both declared as modules in ONE (packaging jar).

Comment: Why don't you post you POMs for us?

Comment: I updated with POMs.

Comment: Not reproduced with Eclipse Luna: Imports are resolved 100% OK. I suggest you create a new module project from the scratch, and copy over it the app-module pom and source files, to discard any errors in the Eclipse project's metadata files.

Comment: I tried a couple of times early without success (deleting and importing my project). I had to restart my lap and I realized that now Eclipse divided my multi-project (separated project). Thanks @LittleSanti, it's working perfect now.